# Is there a way in Hystrix to signal an error to the circuit breaker without using an exception?

Tags: hystrix

I'm using Hystrix in a scenario where some errors are communicated as normal results and not as exceptions.

An example would be an `HystrixObservableCommand` that returns a `Observable<HttpResponse>`:

- If the observable emits a response with status code lower than `500`, then the response should be considered as being successful.
- If the observable emits a response with status code greater or equal than `500`, or if it emits a `Throwable`, then the response should be considered to be an error and the circuit breaker error stats should be incremented.

I really don't want to throw an exception just to have Hystrix consider the response as an error.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks,
Pedro

Comment: can you give an example. It is much easier to suggest

Comment: Edited the question to make it a little more clearer. Thanks.

Comment: check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47708195/is-it-possible-to-selectively-ignore-service-exception-in-hystrix/47710614#47710614

Comment: Thanks. However I need the reverse behaviour. I need Hystrix to consider a non-exception outcome as an error.

Comment: but why do you not want to throw an exception

Comment: Because in my architecture some type of errors should not be communicated via an exception. A good example is an HTTP 500 response from a remote server.

Comment: when you throw an exception from the method, it will not be propagated to the client. With the exception, tcontrol goes to fallback function, where you can control what is returned to the client

Comment: It still implies throwing an exception but a seems a good idea. Let me try it out.